# elasticsearch sorting in aggregation not working

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

I am using aggregation to group a field based on the sum of other field.

It's working but the output is not similar to the one I am getting from database query.

ES query:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 0
,
    "aggs": {"domain_agg": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "domain_name.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "domain_store_count_sum": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "store_count"
                    }
                },
                "domain_store_count_agg": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "domain_store_count_sum": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size": 5
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    },
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "(*:*) "
        }
    }
}
```

output:

> "domain_agg": {
>       "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 9,
>       "sum_other_doc_count": 1442,
>       "buckets": [
>           {
>               "key": "advanceautoparts.com",
>               "doc_count": 2,
>               "domain_store_count_sum": {
>                   "value": 11258
>               }
>           },
>           {
>               "key": "tesla.com",
>               "doc_count": 3,
>               "domain_store_count_sum": {
>                   "value": 6795
>               }
>           },
>           {
>               "key": "aldi.us",
>               "doc_count": 2,
>               "domain_store_count_sum": {
>                   "value": 3678
>               }
>           },
>           {
>               "key": "alamo.com",
>               "doc_count": 2,
>               "domain_store_count_sum": {
>                   "value": 566
>               }
>           },
>           {
>               "key": "ajg.com",
>               "doc_count": 2,
>               "domain_store_count_sum": {
>                   "value": 440
>               }
>           }
>       ] }

But when I ran the same in database I got differrent output.

DB query:

```
SELECT domain_name, SUM(store_count) AS store_count
FROM table
GROUP BY domain_name order by store_count desc
```

Output:

```
'subway.com','57384'
'bmoharris.com','56876'
'peets.com','37472'
'citibank.com','32348'
'shell.us','23016'
```

Why I am getting different result in elasticsearch, while both have the same data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to precise the mapping in your main agg:

```
"field": "domain_name.keyword" => "field": "domain_name"
```

and you should remove the query part.

```
"query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "(*:*) "
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, 
I am getting the below error,
{
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [domain_name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
            }

Comment: Please find the mappings,
{"aaaa":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"doc":{"properties":{"domain_name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"","version":{"created":""},"provided_name":"aaaa"}}}}

Comment: Yeah, that s why you got an error message. Your domain_name field is not a keyword, this is a text.  So elasticindex it in some way but he cant be use in aggregation except if (as the error msg say) you set FieldData to true (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html). According to your context, maybe you made a mistake in your mappings, and this field should be map as a keyword.